# property file to json, Java code

Tags: java, json, properties-file

//  My property file :

```
   key1 = value1
   key2 = value2,value3
   key3 = value4, value5, value6

Requirement in json
  "Arguments":  
   {  
     "key1":"value1",
      "key2":["value2","value3"]   
      "key3":["value4","value5","value6"]
   }
```

// Please provide me the java code

Comment: Of course. Do you want coffee with the code too ?

Comment: First you need to mention the problem you're trying to solve
How do I ask a good question? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The problem is how to put the multiple values of a key to a json object. Like key2 and key3 in above example. Single value we can do.

Answer (score 0):

Put your "Arguments" into a class, I'm going to call it `Argument`. Then use [`Gson`](https://github.com/google/gson) to serialise this class to JSON.

Like the following:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
String response = gson.toJson(argumentInstance);
Files.write(path, Arrays.asList(response.split("\n")));
```

You can then read it back like so, providing the class:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
argumentInstance = gson.fromJson(Files.newBufferedReader(path), Argument);
```

Comment: Thank you. It helps